Converting pkcs8 node crypto to web crypto (Apple Mapkit-js token)
I have succesfully wrote this Apple Mapkit token generator in Node.js:
function buildTokenNode() {
  const header = {
    alg: 'ES256',
    kid: process.env.APPLE_MAPS_P8_KEY_ID,
    typ: 'JWT'
  };

  const epoch = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

  const claims = {
    iss: process.env.APPLE_TEAM_ID,
    iat: epoch,
    // Expire in 7 days
    exp: epoch + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  };

  const headerBase64 = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(header)).toString('base64');
  const claimsBase64 = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(claims)).toString('base64');

  const unsignedToken = `${headerBase64}.${claimsBase64}`;

  const signer = crypto.createSign('sha256');
  signer.write(unsignedToken);
  signer.end();

  const signature = signer
    .sign(process.env.APPLE_MAPS_P8_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'), 'base64')
    .replace(/=/g, '')
    .replace(/\+/g, '-')
    .replace(/\//g, '_');

  const signedToken = `${unsignedToken}.${signature}`;

  return signedToken;
}

However, I am not trying to use edge runtime which doesn't have node-crypto, but gives web crypto - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/edge#crypto-apis
I came up with this so far, however I keep getting "invalid keyData":
async function buildTokenWebCrypto() {
  const header = {
    alg: 'ES256',
    kid: process.env.APPLE_MAPS_P8_KEY_ID,
    typ: 'JWT'
  };

  const epoch = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

  const claims = {
    iss: process.env.APPLE_TEAM_ID,
    iat: epoch,
    // Expire in 7 days
    exp: epoch + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
  };

  const headerBase64 = encodeBase64(JSON.stringify(header));
  const claimsBase64 = encodeBase64(JSON.stringify(claims));

  const unsignedToken = `${headerBase64}.${claimsBase64}`;

  // Convert the unsignedToken to an ArrayBuffer
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  const unsignedTokenBuffer = encoder.encode(unsignedToken);

  const theKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    'pkcs8',
    encoder.encode(process.env.APPLE_MAPS_P8_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')),
    {
      name: 'ECDSA',
      namedCurve: 'P-256'
    },
    false,
    ['sign']
  );
  // Sign the data using the private key
  const signature = await crypto.subtle.sign(
    {
      name: 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5',
      hash: { name: 'SHA-256' }
    },
    theKey,
    unsignedTokenBuffer
  );

  const signatureBase64 = btoa(
    String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(signature))
  );

  const signedToken = `${unsignedToken}.${signatureBase64}`;

  return signedToken;
}

function encodeBase64(str) {
  const uint8Array = new TextEncoder().encode(str);
  let binary = '';
  uint8Array.forEach(byte => {
    binary += String.fromCharCode(byte);
  });
  return btoa(binary);
}

Any ideas on how to write this in web crypto?
